# when i am executing this script i am getting this error like "activex component can't create object "scripting.dictonary",what does it mean?

Tags: qtp

```
Dim dictObject Set dictObject=CreateObject("Scripting .dictonary") dictObject.Add "italy","rome" dictObject.Add "country","india" dictObject.Add "state","karnataka" dictObject.Add "dist","bangalore" Print dictObject.Count.
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't create an object called "Scripting.dictonary".
Maybe it is called "Scripting.dictionary" (notice the "i").

Answer (score 0):

add "i" in dictonary 
delete space in ("Scripting .dictonary")
it works.